# FullCalendar excluding weekends return invalid date on changing view from month or agendaWeek to agendaDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i have another issue on `FullCalendar`.
I have `activated` the `today` button, and also have set `weekends` to `false`.
However, for example on

- Sunday 2 November 2014

(this is the actual date this question is published), if i hit the `today` button from month of agendaWeek i get in `agendaDay` view

- November 2, 2014 and day `Monday`

which is obviously wrong, since the correct date is

- Monday November 3 2014.

Is any sort of solution or setting to this, or i would just have to either permanently avoid `today` button or hide it with `js` during weekends?

Comment: Title says "... on changing view". From what to what?

Comment: from month of agendaWeek to agendaDay..thanks for pointing it out, i ll fix it right away..

Comment: You might like to spell out explicitly in the text - which behaviour you observe in each of the views. Suggest you use bullet points.